# Building Semivariogram/Variogram in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kriging, variogram

I am trying to Interpolate Point Data in QGIS using the Ordinary Kriging Modul (SAGA) from the processing menu.

Is it possible to build a Semivariogram in QGIS or call the SAGA Variogramm function from QGIS?

Without a possibility to define range, sill and nugget the Kriging module seems usless to me.

Comment: The processing toolbox has SAGA `variogram cloud` and `variogram surface` algorithms.

Comment: Thank you but a variogram cloud or surface isn't the same as a variogram plot.

Comment: I think you have two options in QGIS (1) Use R script (rsx) through the Processing Toolbox, or (2) Eyeballing variogram by using spreadsheet (e.g. MS-Excel) from the output of variogram cloud as suggested by @csk.

Comment: @ Kazuhito: Thanks a lot! A new problem: The Plugin "Processing R Provider" is only supported by QGIS 3.4 or higher but the SAGA Kriging Modul doesn't seem to work in the latest QGIS Versions, but does so with QGIS 3.2!

Comment: @Rob Sorry I did not know that. I have overlooked something. (It works in my environment, but plugins are sensitive to OS and affected by various things).